# WordPress wp get_temp_dir return non exiting folder, thus failing plugin & themes update

Tags: plugins, themes, wp-config, upgrade

Problem: All pluging & themes updates fail on `folder does not exist or unavialble` (WP. 5.3.2)

After research I found that in `wp-admin/file.php` in function: `download_url`

the call to  `wp_tempnam()` returns non existing folder. Causing the update to fail.

More info:

1. wp-config has `define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/');`  above call to `wp-settings.php`
2. No definitions in database: wp_options for upload dir. - to use defaults.
3. All needed folders exists with propper mode `0755`
4. Changing theme to default 2020 did not help (verify that no other code is involved)

All the above did not help. Only when I override the result of `wp_tempnam()` in file.php all works well.

Question: `wp_tempnam()` uses `get_temp_dir()` which returns the wrong part of the path. What am I missing? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Perhaps `777` would work.. but then, why don't you just use the default system path?

Comment: I try to use defaults...  I did not provide any setting.

Comment: I'm saying, why do you need to define the `WP_TEMP_DIR`? If you don't define it, the default system path would be used. And by the "777", I mean setting the directory permission to `0777`...

Comment: Totally agree. I am debugging a plugin... its not my code.

Comment: Well, I tried setting a custom `WP_TEMP_DIR` and things worked for me (i.e. `wp_tempnam()` returned a valid temporary file), except I didn't test with plugin/theme updates. So does using `0777` work? But if it's not your code, then how about *not* using the custom `WP_TEMP_DIR` value? Using the `wp-content` is also, IMO, not a good idea. The default (which is normally out of the 'public' site directory) should be fine in most cases.

Comment: @SallyCJ I replaced the plugin...